# make the veress follow the balloon as it inflates

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm new to Unity and I have two objects in the game, the veress and the balloon, I want to make the veress change its height while the balloon inflates

i write a code but it dosen't work correctly it turn down under my object not on top, the logic that i want to do it is  to calculate every frame the height of the ballon and add it to the position.y of the versee , can any one help me:

`

```
public class Infalte : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject stomach;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool isMaxSize = false;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool isRightHeight = false;

    [SerializeField]
    private float timer = 0f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float maxHeight = 0f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float growTime = 20f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float maxSizeX = 10.2f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float maxSizeY = 9.6f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float maxSizeZ = 4.5f;

    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject Veress;
    private float lastY = 0.0f;

    [ContextMenu("pneumoperitoneum ")]
    public void StartInsufflation()
    {
        if (isMaxSize == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Inflate());
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator Inflate()
    {
        Vector3 startScale = transform.localScale;
        Vector3 maxScale = new Vector3(maxSizeX, maxSizeY, maxSizeZ);
        if (isRightHeight == false)
        {
            transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0, 0.0f, 0);
            isRightHeight = true;
        }
        int frames = 0;
        do
        {
            frames++;

            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, maxScale, timer / growTime);
            timer += Time.deltaTime;

            if (frames == 20)
                {
                    frames = 0;
                stomach.GetComponent<MDM_MeshFit>().MeshFit_UpdateMeshState();
                float currentScaleY = Veress.transform.position.y;

                Vector3 newPosition = Veress.transform.position;
                newPosition.y = Mathf.Lerp(-currentScaleY, lastY, timer / growTime);
                Veress.transform.position = newPosition;
            }

            yield return null;
        } while (timer < growTime);
        isMaxSize = true;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Why did you repost this instead of editing the original question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76096708/have-the-veress-follow-the-balloon-as-it-inflates